# Select from table after a cel value

Tags: mysql

I want to select from MySQL table all records after last value.
This is an example

**MyTable**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    date (DATE)     |Product_id  (INT fk)|   Quantite (INT)   |type (ENUM('S', 'R')|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    2016-09-20      |         1          |         15         |         R          |
|    2016-09-21      |         1          |         20         |         S          |
|    2016-09-23      |         1          |         19         |         R          |
|    2016-09-28      |         1          |         30         |         S          |
|    2016-09-30      |         1          |         20         |         S          |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

i want a query to get the last rows with a type S

this is the output i need

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    date (DATE)     |Product_id  (INT fk)|   Quantite (INT)   |type (ENUM('S', 'R')|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    2016-09-28      |         1          |         30         |         S          |
|    2016-09-30      |         1          |         20         |         S          |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Can you shows us the expected output as well, or explain what you mean by last rows?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Done editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `LIMIT` :

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.type = 'S'
ORDER BY t.date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want it for each ID then you can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                  WHERE s.product_id = t.product_id
                    AND s.type = 'S'
                    AND s.date > t.date)
  AND t.type = 'S'
```

**EDIT:** If I understood you correctly, you want all the record with type `S` after the last record of type `R` , if so :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                  WHERE s.product_id = t.product_id
                    AND s.type = 'R'
                    AND s.date > t.date)
  AND t.type = 'S'
```

Comment: @klaus So, last two records? Change `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT 2` .

Comment: @klaus I don't know if I understood you.. but see edit.